# VueJS - Update Parent Data After Ajax

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying out VueJS, with the aim of incrementally updating a jQuery project, but I'm having issues with props in a child component passed through data from a parent component.

My parent component is

```
// parent_component.js
var parentData = {};
var parentComponent = Vue.component('parentComponent', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            parentData: _parentData
        }
    },
    delimiters: ['((', '))']
})

$.ajax({
   url: '/someUrl/',
   success: function(response) {
      _parentData = response
   }
```

My Child component is:

```
// child_component.js
Vue.component('child-component', {
    template: '<div>((data.someProp))</div>'
    props: ['data'],
    delimiters: ['((', '))']
})
```

My HTML is:

```
// index.html
<parent-component inline-template>
     <child-component v-bind:data="parentData"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

This all works fine when I update `_parentData` right after initializing the childComponent. But I actually need to do an Ajax call and update the _parentData, it is not updated in the childComponent.
Nb. I checked that the _parentData object is there in the callback of the Ajax call.
Also, I tried putting the Ajax call in the `created` option of the childComponent, but this didn't help.

What am I missing?

**Update**

I guess I made the classic beginner's mistake! As stated [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), `Vue cannot detect property addition`. So I need to define the `someProp` property on the _parentData before making the async call.

So if I define `var parentData = { someProp: '' };` it will work.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maaikeb/anr1e88n/

Comment: `success: response => this.parentData = response`.

Answer (score -1):

If you share the AJAX part of code, maybe I can help better, but IMHO I think that the easiest way is `emiting` a event from children, and catch it with the parent element when the AJAX call is done (success or error).

**Events** provide a way to inform your parent components of changes in children.

Template Usage:

```
<my-component v-on:myEvent="parentHandler"></my-component>
<!-- Or more succinctly, -->
<my-component @myEvent="parentHandler"></my-component>
```

Firing an Event:

```
...
export default {
  methods: {
    fireEvent() {
      this.$emit('myEvent', eventValueOne, eventValueTwo);
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, you can create global event buses to pass events anywhere in your app

Extracted from [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-communication/).

**Edit**

Ok, I didn't understand you well, if you have problems sending data `down` from parent to children when updating the parent the proper way is the double data binding.

Maybe your problem is that the `data` is only evaluated in component creation, and your child will be created with the initial value of the parent component...

You can try some different things to solve this, like:

1 - Maybe your issue is related to a change detection [caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Maybe you're creating a new property in an object...

```
 _parentData = response
```

...when you should do...

```
_parentData.$set('someObject.someProperty', someValue)
```

2 - Use `watch` on parent instead of `created`:

```
 watch:{ 
  yourData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/someUrl/',
            content_type: 'application/json',
            data_type: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                 _parentData = response
            }
         })
  },
```

3 - Try using `.sync` ( *deprecated in 2.0* ):

```
<component :something.sync="variable"></component>
```

4 - Bind `.this` to the anonymous AJAX call or use arrow functions as @Bert commented:

```
success: () => (response) {
                 _parentData = response
            }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The ajax call is done from the module where the parent component is created in, not the child component